# can't callback on facebook likes or share

Tags: facebook, dom, iframe, share

I'm currently working on a web app that need to detect when someone is clicking on like or share button. I tried to add the targeted post or page within an iframe. The point is I can't do a callback on like or share because the content of the iframe because it's apparently natively protected for cross origin.

In Facebook Q&A it seems like they don't want to have apps forcing people to like and so they block  this possibility but i'm not sure I got ir right. Is it right? Is there a way I can detect like/share on my web app with or without iframe?

Thanks and have a nice sunday

Comment: what exactly would your use case be? the anwer to that is important to give you a serious answer.

Comment: I would like to give the user some points(in the webapp as a reward score) when he clicks on the button like or share

Comment: to be exact the user login to the website go to another user page and can see some content from facebook and choose to like or share it, when he decides to, the site give him some score for the action

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to give the user some points(in the webapp as a reward score) when he clicks on the button like or share

It is not allowed to reward users for likes or shares. Check out the platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.5

Like and share callbacks do not really work for that anymore anyway. You would need to get the `user_likes` permission reviewed by Facebook, for example.